# Calling an Android function from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview

I have a problem which I need some help with. I'm trying to call an android function by using an angular controller in my frontend, but I can't get it to work.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AngularJSInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.70.101:3000/");

}
```

AngularJSInterface:

```
public class AngularJSInterface {

Context mContext;

AngularJSInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ComplaintCtrl', function ($scope, $http, complaintService) {

    $scope.showToast = function(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
        console.log("toast");
}
```

});

The HTML:

```
<button label="toast" ng-click="showToast('Visar toast från angularJS')">toast</button>
```

Error from console:

```
ReferenceError: Android is not defined
at Scope.$scope.showToast (http://localhost:3000/scripts/controllers/addcomplaint.js:34:3)
at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10567:21
at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:438:9
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12412:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12510:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:437:13)
at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4409:9)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4095:28)
```

This is the first time I'm using this sort of thing and I'm not quite sure how to actually do it. I've tried looking for answers by googling but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Either change your toast function to static and call it directly or instantiate it first. And, you have no class named as `Android` instead you have created `AngularJSInterface`. Change you `Android.showToast` to `AngularJSInterface.showToast` (if using static).

Comment: I've changed the showToast method to static, and replaced Angular.showToast() with AngularJSInterface. showToast(), although I still get the same error (AngularJSInterface is not defined). How exactly whould I instantiate it?

Comment: AngularJSInterface myInterface = new AngularJSInterface(); myInterface.showToast();